# How to change the style of parent div that has a rotated image with CSS in Angular 5 project?

Tags: css, angular

I was building a meme with top and bottom text.
I am in need of rotating an image so I did it with `transform: rotate(90deg);`, but it's overlapped parent's div like the following example.

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: #777;
}

.parent .rotate {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 100px;
}

.parent h4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.parent .top {
  top: 10px;
}

.parent .bottom {
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h4 class="top">Top Text</h4>
  <img class="rotate" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-7uOyzdXhG2Y/UVpJUbwqGzI/AAAAAAAAAo0/35w5N8tPvHE/s640/iphone-5-hd-wallpapers-hd-41664-tpmw7.jpg" />
  <h4 class="bottom">Bottom Text</h4>
</div>
```

How can I change the style of the parent div to match the position and size of the rotated image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to change the `height` of the div to be same as `width`.

We can do it by

```
.parent{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%; /* 1:1 Aspect Ratio */
  position: relative; /* If you want text inside of it */
}
```

Second, we need an additional div inside it that has `absolute` position with full width and height of it.

We can use `flex` to center the image inside that `absolute` div.

Here is a working code.

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}

.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: #777;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.p-absolute {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parent .rotate {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.parent h4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.parent .top {
  top: 10px;
}

.parent .bottom {
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <h4 class="top">Top Text</h4>
    <div class="p-absolute">
      <img class="rotate" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-7uOyzdXhG2Y/UVpJUbwqGzI/AAAAAAAAAo0/35w5N8tPvHE/s640/iphone-5-hd-wallpapers-hd-41664-tpmw7.jpg" />  
    </div>
    <h4 class="bottom">Bottom Text</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```